# Circle CI failed to compile. "cannot be used as a JSX element"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, compiler-errors, circleci

I've been using Circle CI with little issue for 6 months, and suddenly I'm getting this error when compiling:

> 'Draggable' cannot be used as a JSX component.
> Its instance type 'Draggable' is not a valid JSX element.  TS2786

I'm getting this error even when rerunning a build that was previously successful (ie. don't know what could have changed).

Also, I can build the app without issue locally.

I'm using react-draggable, but haven't touched that part of the code with the Draggable component since many previous successful builds.